# Why is this an invalid json?

Tags: json, getjson

Why is this an invalid JSON, I'm also tried putting quotes to the key and doesn't work.

```
{

   Nombre: “Manzana”,

   Imagen: “./img/imagen_manzana.jpg”,

  Descripción: “Manzana rica”,

   PrecioKG: 24,

   Iva: 16,

   Inventario:30
 }, 
{

  Nombre: “Naranja”,

  Imagen: “./img/imagen_naranja.jpg”,

  Descripción: “Naranja rica”,

  PrecioKG: 14,

  Iva: 16,

  Inventario: 27 
}
```

Comment: Because you are using `“` quotes instead of normal `"`.

Comment: no quotes for the keys, wrong quotes for the strings, array brackets missing surrounding everything

Comment: @dfsq Thanks a lot! It is my very first homework with JSON and I got lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For several reasons:

1. The keys are not in double quotes.
2. The strings are quoted with "fancy quotes" (`“`), not correct quotes `"`.
3. You have two top-level values. There can only be one top-level value. If you want two objects, you need to wrap them in an array.

http://jsonlint.com (no affiliation) and other such sites can help you with these things.

Minimal fix:

```
[
    {

      "Nombre": "Manzana",

      "Imagen": "./img/imagen_manzana.jpg",

      "Descripción": "Manzana rica",

      "PrecioKG": 24,

      "Iva": 16,

      "Inventario": 30
  },
  {

      "Nombre": "Naranja",

      "Imagen": "./img/imagen_naranja.jpg",

      "Descripción": "Naranja rica",

      "PrecioKG": 14,

      "Iva": 16,

      "Inventario": 27
  }
]
```